# PEGA SLIDER - and get refresh property

Tags: slider, refresh, visibility, pega

I got a requirement to do a slider in PEGA.

The issue is that I do not manage to get the field/property refreshed with the slider value. I need to use this property in a declare expression and in conditional visibility (layout).

I am looking for something like the autocomplete where the value is refresh without submitting.

Any idear will be welcome.

THX.

Comment: Please add examples of what you have tried, in addition to the code that seems to be causing issues for you. Take a look at Stack Overflow's guidelines on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: In Pega two slider are provided : UI_Slider and pySlider. Inside a dynamic Layout : In a field, I change the field nature by the UI_Slider. The General take the property .Amount, the parameters are min, max and step. The actions are Event : on change and Action: Refresh this section. In a second Dynamic layout, I put a label with the .Amount property.

Comment: OK, that still isn't enough for us to go by. You need to upload some code for us to see- at the moment, all I have is your description of the functionality of how your slider works, from a UI perspective.

Comment: There is no code, PEGA is a framework, that is configured via a browser.

Comment: But it is coded in JAVA and can include JSP and JS code.  So it is more configuration and scriplet use.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have solved the issue. In order to actualise the property .Amount outside the layout, I needed to configure an action on the first layout. The one holding the slider. In this layout -> in actions : add an event: Change and Add an Action : Refresh-This section / Target Section.

The value is then dynamicly refreshed in the clipboard too.

PS : in order to have different step value inside the same slider (ex: from 0 to 10 step = 1, form 10 to 30 step = 3 ... ) just use a property in the Slider Parameters 'step' of the slider and link this property to a declare expression. Within the declare expression you can configure as much step as you want.